# Make UITexftField like android using subclass in swift without any third party

Tags: android, ios, swift3, uitextfield, subclass

[image]

[image]

How to creat Uitextfield look like android text field

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51894057/i-want-customised-uitextfield-which-has-placeholder-behaviour-same-as-android-al/51894109#51894109

Answer (score 0):

**I found this solution, it's working for me.**

**Follow below step for customise `UITextField` like android textfield using subclass.**

1. Create new filed with subclass `UITextField`
2. for Border below `UITextField` : set `tint color` and `lineWidth`as you want.

   ```
   override var tintColor: UIColor! {
       didSet {
           setNeedsDisplay()
       }
   }

   override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

       let startingPoint   = CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY)
       let endingPoint     = CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY)

       let path = UIBezierPath()

       path.move(to: startingPoint)
       path.addLine(to: endingPoint)
       path.lineWidth = 2.0

       tintColor.setStroke()

       path.stroke()
   }
   ```
3. assign `UItextFieldDelegate`
4. Enter below code for asking delegate for this subclass

   ```
   override func awakeFromNib() {    
       self.delegate = self    
   }
   ```
5. Also enter text field `delegate` method `textFieldDidBeginEditing` and `textFieldDidEndEditing`.

   ```
   //MARK: - Textfield Delegate    
   func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
       for view in (textField.superview?.subviews)!{
           if view is UILabel && view.tag == 0{
               let lbl = view as! UILabel
               lbl.isHidden = false
               textField.placeholder = ""
           }
       }
   }

   func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
       if newdelegate != nil{
           newdelegate?.textFieldDidEndEditing!(textField)
       }
       if textField.text?.length == 0{
           for view in (textField.superview?.subviews)!{
               if view is UILabel && view.tag == 0{
                   let lbl = view as! UILabel
                   lbl.isHidden = true
                   textField.placeholder = lbl.text
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
6. Make structure in `storyboard` and assign this `subclass` to this `UItextField`

[image]

Hope it's helpful to you
Thank you enjoy.  :)

Answer (score 0):

1. First in your xib file go to attributes inspection.
2. Open right pane.
3. Select attributes inspection
4. In border style apply none i.e select one with dotted lines.
5. After that in your swift file add following method:

   ```
   func textViewUnderline(textField: UITextField)**
   { 
      let border = CALayer()
      let width = CGFloat(1.0)  

      border.borderColor = UIColor.yourColorforBorderHere.cgColor

      border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: textField.frame.size.height - width, 
   width:  textField.frame.size.width, height: textField.frame.size.height)

      border.borderWidth = width

      textField.layer.masksToBounds = true
      textField.layer.addSublayer(border)
   }
   ```
6. Call this method by passing your uitextfield in viewDidLoad as:

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad()
   {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      textViewUnderline(textField: yourUITextField)
   }
   ```

Comment: Bro use this code it will surely work ... do let me know for any errors or confusions I will help you out and if it works dont forget this solution to mark as answer to your question? Happy coding :)